# prove following combinatorial identity

Tags: combinatorics, summation, permutations, combinations, binomial-coefficients

I have been trying to prove following thing. With no success

> prove that for $n>k\geq 2$ $$\sum_{i=0}^k nP_{(k+i)} . \binom{k}{k-i} kP_{(k-i)} = (nP{k})^2$$ where $nPk = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$

any useful hint is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=0}^k nP_{(k+i)} . \binom{k}{k-i} kP_{(k-i)} = (nP{k})^2$$

$$\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{n!}{(n-k-i)!} \frac{k!}{i!(k-i)!} \frac{k!}{i!} = (\frac{n!}{(n-k)!})^2$$

divide both sides by n! and k! and multiply both sides by (n-k)!.

$$\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{(n-k)!}{(i)!(n-k-i)!} \frac{k!}{i!(k-i)!}  = \frac{n!(n-k)!}{(n-k)!(n-k)!k!}$$

$$\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n-k}{i} \binom{k}{k-i}  = \binom{n}{k}$$

In this form it is a special case of Vandermonde's identity.

Comment: I should maybe have asked if you could use Vandermonde's identity.

Comment: I have written until second line and unable to proceed further. NIce idea to use Vandermonde's identity.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is simpler to prove in this form:
$$\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{i,i,k-i,n-k-i} = \binom{n}{k}^2$$

Comment: what is this notation btw. I don't know it

Comment: It is a multinomial coefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a combinatorial interpretation. We want to count the number of ways to pick two $k$-tuples $A=(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k)$ and $B=(b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_k)$, such that all of these elements are from $[n]$, all of the $a$s are distinct, and all of the $b$s are distinct, though we can have $a_h=b_j$ for some $h$ and $j$.

The right hand side counts this explicitly. To see how the left hand side counts this, let $i$ denote the number of elements that $B$ has that it does not share with $A$. Note that $i$ can go from $0$ to $n$. The factor $nP_{(k+i)}$ counts the number of $(k+i)$-tuples we can form from elements of $[n]$ without repeating any. The first $k$ of those elements, in that order, form $A$. The remaining $i$ elements will be elements of $B$. Since those $i$ elements are the ones that are unique to $B$, the other $k-i$ elements of $B$ will be from $A$, and the factor $kP_{(k-i)}$ counts how many ways we can pick those elements in some order. Finally, the factor ${k\choose k-i}$ gives a set of indices from $k$ where we can place the $k-i$ elements from $A$ we picked, in the order we picked them in, and the other $i$ elements unique to $B$ are placed in the remaining $i$ places. This gives the desired $A$ and $B$.

For example, consider $n=9$, $k=5$, and $i=2$. The factor $9P7$ gives us a $7$-tuple using elements from $[9]$ without repetition, such as $(3, 9, 8, 1, 4, 2, 6)$. The first $5$ of those elements gives us $A=(3,9,8,1,4)$, and we will use $(2, 6)$ in $B$. The factor $5P3$ gives us a $3$-tuple of elements from $A$, such as $(4, 9, 1)$. We then use the factor ${5\choose 3}$ to pick a subset such as $\{1, 2, 4\}$, which we use as a set of indices to place the elements $4$, $9$, and $1$ in $B$, and place $2$ and $6$ in the remaining places. That gives us $B=(4, 9, 2, 1, 6)$, and we have the $A$ and $B$ that are counted by the right hand side.